# How can I set Mongoose document field to current date in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB schema looking like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    meetings: [
        {
            actions: [         
                {
                    item: String,    //"meeting 1", "meeting 2", etc   
                    status: String,  //"complete", "todo"
                    completed: Date
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {collection: 'user'});
```

How can I set the Date here in Node.js when I get a method call? To be more specific, when my function gets called, a user `_id` and an `action.item` will be given. I will need to use the user `_id` and the `action.item` to locate Mongoose user document and subsequently set the corresponding action `status` to `"complete"` and `complete` to the current date in Node.js. How do I set the Date?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you want to set `default` date when `model` is created, you can provide `default` to the model like this.

```
actions: [         
            {
               item: String,    //"meeting 1", "meeting 2", etc   
               status: String,  //"complete", "todo"
               completed: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
             }
          ]
```

This will `default` current `Date` when model is called.

Comment: Hi, the model is already set. I am trying to modify the model and confuse about how to set the date to the function called time. I get an error Type `'{ type: DateConstructor; default: () => number; }' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'type' does not exist in type 'Date'.ts(2322)` using completed: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

Answer (score 0):

In your post request, before you call the `save()` method, use

```
const date = Date.now();
```

So use `req.body` where you need and for the date just use what I wrote a line ago.
You can also store it as a string. Change the `type` on the model to `string` and in the post request write:

```
const date = Date.now().toISOString();
```